# @testing-library/react-native How should I test the BackHandler Alert and handle ok and cancel button?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, testing-library, react-native-testing-library

Unable to test this below code using @testing-library/react-native

````
    useCallback(() => {
      const onBackPress = () => {
        Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to Exit?", [
          {
            text: "Cancel",
            onPress: () => null,
            style: "cancel"
          },
          { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
        ]);
        return true;
      };
      BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", onBackPress);
      return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", onBackPress);
    }, []));```
````